# Async operation immediately awaited

Tags: c#

I'm looking at these lines of code from another developer:

```
  bool isValid = await engine.GetTaskByIdAsync(taskId);
  if(isValid )
  ....
```

When I work with `async` operations, it is to do independent work while the async operation completes:

```
  Task<bool> task = engine.GetTaskByIdAsync(taskId);

  //Do work that doesn't need the "task" variable

  bool completed = await task;
  if(bool)
  ....
```

It appears that the first example kicks off an async operation and then immediately starts waiting. Is there some value here I don't understand?

Note: this code is in the data access layer of an application, so it isn't interacting with a user interface.

Comment: Sure, kick off a process and immediately return, what's it matter if you have logic beforehand?

Comment: "It appears that the first example kicks off an async operation and then immediately starts waiting" - `await` causes us to wait for the call to complete before proceeding.

Comment: How would you do what that programmer did *without* awaiting the task?

Comment: @DanPantry No.  It doesn't.  That's, sadly, a common misconception.  It causes the remainder of the method to be wired up as a continuation for the awaited task, executing it when that task completes.  That's very different than waiting on that task.

Comment: The use of immediately awaiting is to facilitate not locking the User Interface.

Comment: @Servy I feel so stupid now. ;-;.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is there some value here I don't understand?

Absolutely - it means that although you need the value returned by the operation before you can do any more work, you're not tying up a thread while you're waiting for it. That's particularly important if you're writing a GUI, where tying up the GUI thread basically means freezing the UI.

It sounds like you're focusing on the "doing multiple things in parallel" side of asynchrony, which is important, but far from the only benefit of it.

Comment: Good point, I work exclusively with web so it's not something I typically deal with. This code I found in a data access layer, so was curious if there was something to be gleaned from it.

Comment: @ChrisHardie A web application can still benefit from asynchrony.  It can allow web requests to not consume the time of a thread pool thread when not performing CPU bound work, allowing those thread pool threads to service other requests, allowing the server to scale up the number of possible concurrent requests it can service.

Comment: @Servy Wouldn't you be better off raising the number of threads available to the webserver in the first place? Adding await does introduce overhead, but doesn't magically increase the number of cpu cycles available to the system. While you are technically right I'd argue you're better off tuning your webserver correctly.

Comment: @AVee Threads can't scale to infinity.  They have costs.  Not consuming a thread's time when you don't actually have anything for it to do means you don't need as many threads to get a given amount of work done.  If you already are running as many threads as your hardware can support, then that means getting more work done.  The whole idea here isn't that you're getting more throughput out of your CPU; it's that you're not consuming a thread's time *when you have no CPU bound work for it to do*.  It's all about efficiently doing *non-CPU bound* work.

Comment: @Servy All true, but await still needs a thread to do the actual work, it's just a different thread you're blocking. That's very useful when the thread you're working on is, as Jon says, the ui thread, or when the thread you're working on can do something useful in the mean time. Otherwise it only adds extra overhead.

Comment: @AVee No, `await` does *not* need an actual thread to do any work.  The whole *point* of asynchronous is that you don't actually use threads unless you have CPU bound work to be doing on them.  There really is no thread when doing non-CPU bound work in a correctly written asynchronous program.

Comment: @Servy, I'm really not getting there. Let's assume the method being awaited is purely I/O (which isn't my impression of the method in the question). If we run it synchronously the current thread will be suspended allowing another thread to run and do something useful. The cost of this will be a context switch. If we await it instead we allow the thread to be returned to the threadpool, so it can do something useful. The expense of this will be having to save the context so it can be restored later. This replaced a context switch with a different context switch, where's the gain?

Comment: That is, in this case, where the async method is awaited immediately. I can see the case when work is done after calling the async method and before the await.

Comment: @AVee: Suppose you have 1000 requests executing simultaneously, all of which need to perform an IO-based operation taking a second (a web service call, for example). Using async/await, you can get away with a single thread (or rather, only as many threads as are actually able to do work simultaneously). Making the calls synchronously, you need 1000 threads, all blocked and doing nothing but sucking up 1GB of stack space between them. Basically, you're assuming that blocked threads are free - Servy and I are saying they're not.

Comment: @JonSkeet, so you end up with a memory optimization, because await is more lightweight (at least memory wise, which will probably help performance as well). I can see how that helps, although I'd expect to find something like that at the OS level instead of the VM. I'll try to drive into it some more run some tests on it should I find the time. Thanks for the explanation so far.

Answer (score 0):

The commonly made mistake is that await blocks. It doesn't.

The current thread returns immediately and the remainder of the function is registered to be executed when the asynchronous Task completes.